# C/C++ Visual Studio Community Anonymous struct

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I want to be able to do this in visual studio:

```
struct A
{
    int x;
};

struct B
{
    int y;
    struct A;
};

struct B b;
b.x //...
```

How can I do this? In gcc you use -fms-extensions to compile it

Comment: This`struct A;` has to be `struct A A;` at least.

Comment: How do you compile it?   Or how do you implement that?  Probably just me but I'm confused lol.

Comment: MSVS [seems to support it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cx9y4f%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) as an extension. Perhaps, you have to find how to enable extensions in MSVS? Btw, I would use *anonymous structures* from C11 instead of going -fms-extensions. Note that C++ doesn't support anon structs.

Comment: please pick a language, either C or C++ they have distinct and different answers to this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14248044/560648

Comment: There is no such thing as "C/C++".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *just do it*. [MSVS supports this as an extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cx9y4f%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).