# VS2015 rejects in-class initialization in unnamed type

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

The following code fails to compile in VS2015.

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int value) { }
};

struct Moo
{
    struct
    {
        Foo foo = 0;
    } fooHolder;
};


int main()
{
    Moo moo;
}
```

The following error is shown.

```
1>c:\xxx\main.cpp(81): error C2512: 'Foo' : no appropriate default constructor available
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'Moo::<unnamed-type-fooHolder>::(void) restrict(cpu, amp)'
```

If the unnamed struct is given a name, the code compiles.

```
struct NamedHolder
{
    Foo foo = 0;
} fooHolder;
```

The code compiled in clang and gcc. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b4ab035a967eed9

Is it rejecting valid code?

Comment: @101010 I didn't know that. By valid I mean standard compliant.

Comment: I have Visual C++ 2015 00322-20000-00000-AA794 and works fine.

Comment: @101010 Do you have the Update 1 RC installed? My version is 00322-90053-68603-AA603.

Comment: @101010 This question hints that unnamed structs are mentioned in the standard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248044/are-anonymous-structs-standard-and-really-what-are-they It also shows the difference to non-standard anonymous structs.

Comment: No I don't have RC installed, furthermore the example compiles in rextester VC++ as well http://rextester.com/XMEP66067. The standard refers only to anonymous unions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is perfectly fine and it compiles with VS2015 Update 1 RC (just verified). Maybe you're missing something . The system on which I tested :

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
>
> Version 14.0.24627.00 Update 1 RC
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework
>
> Version 4.6.01040
>
> Installed Version: Community
>
> Visual C++ 2015 RC   00322-20000-00000-AA392
> Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 RC
>
> ...

Comment: I had it configured to use the VS2013 compiler.