# too many initializes for Union Structure array

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

This code is just to test my knowledge on structure array access. When I executed this code it gives me the error two many initializes for param. Please help me to understand the error and fixing this problem.
I was trying to reuse the code which is already solved by someone. My question about  fill the Struct with parameters Param_u param

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define ARRAY_COUNT(arr) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof *(arr))

typedef union {
    struct {    // Function parameters
        int *array;
        size_t size;
    };
    struct {    // Function return value
        float mean;
        int Median;
    };
} Param_u;

int main() {
    int array_1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int  ret1, ret2;

    // Fill the Struct with parameters
    Param_u param = {
        .array = array_1,
        .size = ARRAY_COUNT(array_1),
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:28:5: error: too many initializers for 'Param_u'
     };

Comment: clang also gives an error. See live demo [here](http://rextester.com/PNAALV26498) . Which version of clang you are using ?

Comment: Standard C++ does not have designated initializers

Comment: @TestEngineer: which C++ compiler you are using & tell us the version of that compiler ?

Comment: @WorldSEnder: use `-pedantic-errors` option on godbolt & then it will fail in compilation !!!

Comment: I tried in GCC-4.9.2

Comment: Is my program correct?, union with 2 struct and accessing struct 1 array in main function

Answer (score 0):

This is not standard C++. You are using anonymous `struct` & designated initializers (C99 feature). C++ doesn't support that. Enable `-pedantic-errors` option on clang++ & `g++`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248044/are-anonymous-structs-standard-and-really-what-are-they) question for more details. You are using compiler specific extensions so your program is not portable.

See live demo [here](http://rextester.com/PNAALV26498).

`clang++` gives following diagnostics:

```
Error(s):

source_file.cpp:12:5: error: anonymous structs are a GNU extension [-Werror,-Wgnu-anonymous-struct]
    struct {    // Function parameters
    ^
source_file.cpp:16:5: error: anonymous structs are a GNU extension [-Werror,-Wgnu-anonymous-struct]
    struct {    // Function return value
    ^
source_file.cpp:28:9: error: designated initializers are a C99 feature [-Werror,-Wc99-extensions]
        .array = array_1,
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
source_file.cpp:29:9: error: designated initializers are a C99 feature [-Werror,-Wc99-extensions]
        .size = ARRAY_COUNT(array_1),
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
source_file.cpp:24:16: warning: unused variable 'ret2' [-Wunused-variable]
    int  ret1, ret2;
               ^
source_file.cpp:27:13: warning: unused variable 'param' [-Wunused-variable]
    Param_u param = {
            ^
source_file.cpp:24:10: warning: unused variable 'ret1' [-Wunused-variable]
    int  ret1, ret2;
         ^
3 warnings and 4 errors generated.
```