# How to cope with Microsoft extensions?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I included `<windows.h>` header into my project, and I received following error:

> Error C2467: illegal declaration of anonymous 'struct' (wingdi.h)

`wingdi.h` header (it contains anonymous struct within `_devicemodeW`) is included by `windows.h`. Such situation conflicts with my current language settings (disable language extensions `/Za`)  As I understand, WinApi **always** uses language extensions and if I want to use winapi I should always use language extensions? (I am using msvc2015)

Comment: Sadly that's the case. Microsoft adds language extension because it facilitates their own code. But if you think about, they aren't alone. The LINUX kernel is written with a fair bit of GCC extensions in use. I suggest implementing an abstraction layer for what you need. That way you can build just a couple of files with extensions enabled

Comment: @StoryTeller The Linux kernel's header files aren't an SDK for application development.  I've never had too enable some GCC extension to be able to use GNU C LIbrary (glibc) headers.  Many useful GCC extensions are **conforming**; they can be left enabled even in compilation modes that implement all required ISO C diagnostics, and recognize all ISO C constructs.

Comment: You can specify /Za on each individual source code file in the project.  So simply move code that requires the #include into a file that you then can compile without it.  Which then automatically becomes the one that you will have to tinker with when you have to port.  Easy peasy.

Comment: @Kaz - Yes, the public windows headers are bad. The point about compiler extensions to facilitate specific projects, still stands however. And many GCC extensions *are not* conforming as well. So I have no idea what point you are arguing.

Comment: @Kaz infinite support for header files that don't make compiling gruesome

Comment: See [Are "anonymous structs" standard? And, really, what \*are\* they?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248044/are-anonymous-structs-standard-and-really-what-are-they) for discussion, as well as the workaround: `#define NONAMELESSUNION`. This disables anonymous structures and unions.

Comment: @RaymondChen System headers responding to identifiers in an ordinary namespace ... grrr!

Comment: @Kaz News flash: System headers also inject tons of identifiers into an ordinary namespace.