# C Language - struct declaration and inner static members

Tags: c, struct, static

I've found the following example in a technical book

```
struct {
    tBoolean logON;
    static enum eLogLevel outputLevel[NUM_LOG_SUBSYSTEM];
} sLogStruct;
static struct sLogStruct gLogData;
```

but I was confused about the goodness of the struct declaration that, formally, should rather be

```
struct name {
    ...
}
```

in fact, I make some trial and the compiler comes out with an error at the statement (I really tried with standard types and not with something like *sLogStruct*)

```
static struct sLogStruct gLogData;
```

Is my doubt right and the code is faulty?

In addition I'd like to understand the meaning and the scope of *static* class storage within a struct as I did't find any satisfying explanation. Let's have a struct declaration like this

```
struct myStruct {
    int Foo;
    static int sFoo;
} strA, strB;
```

does *strA* and *strB* have two static variable indipendent to one another?

Comment: You can't declare struct members as static in C.

Comment: It would seem that the book is really bad.

Comment: Are you sure the book was using C and not C++?

Comment: Also, `struct { /* Something or other */ } myVariable;` defines an *anonymous* structure, and then defines a variable `myVariable` using this anonymous structure. Or perhaps you missed a `typedef` before `struct`? Because `typedef struct { /* ... */ } myTypename;` defines an anonymous structure and then make a type alias to use the structure.

Comment: Lastly, you seem to have two different questions in this question, which makes it to broad. Please keep it to one question per question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: *Anonymous struct* is reserved for the case where you have an *unnamed struct* inside another one.

Comment: @Acorn Why would they be reserved for nested structures only? You could use it to define any structure variable anywhere just like any other variable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I tried to look up a reference for that. It seems in the C99 Standard there is no usage of "anonymous" (there is of "unnamed", though). In the C++ Standard, however, they define "anonymous union": "it defines an unnamed type and an unnamed object of that type called an anonymous union object". Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248044/are-anonymous-structs-standard-and-really-what-are-they (for C++)

Comment: The [C11 standard §6.7.2.1 ¶2 Structure and union specifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p2) says: _A struct-declaration that does not declare an anonymous structure or anonymous union
shall contain a struct-declarator-list._  (¶13 is also highly relevant.) Thus, in C11 (but not C99 or C90), there are anonymous structures and unions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: In the C11 standard (6.7.2.1.13), though, they say: "An unnamed member of structure type with no tag is called an anonymous structure; an unnamed member of union type with no tag is called an anonymous union. The members of an anonymous structure or union are considered to be members of the containing structure or union. This applies recursively if the containing structure or union is also anonymous."

Comment: @Acorn "Anonymous" or "unnamed" doesn't matter, it's still allowed to declare variables using "unnamed" structures in any scope or context where variable definitions are allowed. The `struct { ... }` is simply the type, like `int` or `struct some_named_structure`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: My comment was only pointing out that your example `struct { /* Something or other */ } myVariable;` defines an unnamed structure, not an anonymous one. I thought it was a good idea to clarify it since this question is specifically asking about unnamed structures. In other words, I didn't mean to nitpick.

Comment: @Acorn It's okay. English is not my native language, so there might be nuances between "anonymous" and "unnamed" that I don't know about, even though I consider them synonymous.

Comment: What book did you find this in?

Comment: author: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3avy280G6I

Comment: @John Bode, Elecia White "Making Embedded Systems"

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes I'm sure it's talking about C

Comment: @JohnBode yes it's "Making Embedded System". It's a good book w.r.t concepts, not about programming languages!

Comment: @MFrancone: Yeah, even good references have mistakes in them - stuff just manages to get past editors and proofreaders.  I was simply curious where the OP found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag name of a `struct` is optional.

For instance, the following would declare two variables (`s1`, `s2`) of an unnamed `struct` type:

```
struct
{
    int a;
} s1, s2;

void f()
{
    s1.a = 3;
    s2.a = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is my doubt right and the code is faulty?

Yes, somehow the code is faulty.

Let's take a closer look:

```
struct {
  tBoolean logON;
  static enum eLogLevel outputLevel[NUM_LOG_SUBSYSTEM];
} sLogStruct;
```

Let's assume you define the types of the members somewhere.

You declare an unnamed struct type and define a **variable** `sLogStruct` of that type.
There is **no struct tag** and **no type name** defined.

```
static struct sLogStruct gLogData;
```

As there is no type `struct sLogStruct`, you cannot define a variable of that type.

> In addition I'd like to understand the meaning and the scope of static class storage within a struct as I did't find any satisfying explanation.

There is no meaning. For struct members it does not make any sense to add `static` keyword and it is not allowed.

Comment: Based on the above comments I think that the struct declaration brings to an unnamed struct rather a anonymous one.
Apart of this, your answer has been helpful!

Comment: @MFrancone thanks for the hint. For me the words were synonyms until now. I updated the answer.

Comment: I neither knew anonymous nor unnamed until now! Try to get a glance to the link posted in the @jonathanLeffler comment. Paragraph 13 and the examples are quite clear.