# Difference between struct S { int align; }; (name after struct keyword) and struct { int align; } S; (name after the struct definition)

Tags: c++, c, struct, kernighan-and-ritchie

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Header
{
    unsigned long long int alignment;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct Header header;  // note: we can loose the 'struct' in C++
    struct Header* pheader = &header;

    return 0;
}
```

The program above compiles perfectly in both C and C++.

But when i change the Header struct to:

```
struct {
    unsigned long long int alignment;
} Header;
```

it fails with the following message in C:
`error: storage size of ‘Header’ isn’t known`

and in C++:
`error: aggregate ‘main()::Header header’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined struct Header header;`

A similar structure is used in the implementation of the Storage Allocator in the C programming Language book by K&R. I thought it was the same thing, but I learn that it isn't. I have since seen in other places as well. I am of course more familiar with the first version. What does the second one mean and why does it even exist? What is the difference?

Comment: Missing a `typedef` in the [case where it's a trailing name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c)..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are "anonymous structs" standard? And, really, what \*are\* they?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248044/are-anonymous-structs-standard-and-really-what-are-they)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`struct Header {};` introduces a `struct` type named `Header`.

`typedef struct {} Header;` introduces an anonymous struct type, and an alias `Header` for that anonymous type.

`struct {} Header;` introduces both an anonymous struct type, and a variable named `Header` of the anonymous  type.

When there is no type named `Header` (the last case), `struct Header header;` introduces a `struct` type named `Header` without a body, then tries to create a variable `header` of that type.

Comment: @Nik-Lz In C++, `decltype(Header)` can be used to extract the (anonymous) type of `Header`.  In C, I don't believe there is a way to name the type of `Header` and use it on anything else.

Answer (score 1):

When you are compiling below portion

```
struct {
    unsigned long long int alignment;
} Header;
```

`struct` has no **tag**, it's called **anonymous structure** type. while doing

```
struct Header header;
```

compiler produces an error like

> Header header’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined struct Header
>   header

Hence in these cases it's better to `typedef` the `struct`. For e.g

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned long long int alignment;
} Header;
```

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, the compiler sees "Header" and doesn't have a previous or built in data type of "Header" so it doesn't know what it is. When you use

```
typedef struct header {
    ....
} Header;
```

The compiler can say hey the user told me a defined data type and now I can have something to reference later on in the code.