# Import structs as nested, anonymous structs in union using C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, nested, unions, anonymous-struct

Please consider the following "unchangeable" declarations:

```
typedef struct T_MESSAGE
{
    unsigned int  uiTimestamp;
    unsigned char ucDataType;
    unsigned int  uiDataSize;
    unsigned char aucData[1024];
} TT_MESSAGE;

typedef struct T_SENSORDATA_HEADER
{
    unsigned char ucSensorType;
    unsigned char ucMountingPoint;
} TT_SENSORDATA_HEADER;
```

In case the message contains Sensor Data, the data is stored within the aucData array, always beginning with the Sensor Data Header. I would like to create a union or struct, which allows me to directly access all members of such a message, without having to use another variable name.
I hope you understand what I want to do by looking at my previous attempts.
I tried it like this:

```
union SensorDataMessage
{
    struct T_Message;

    struct
    {
        unsigned : 32;  // Skip uiTimestamp
        unsigned : 8;   // Skip ucDataType
        unsigned : 32;  // Skip uiDataSize

        struct T_SENSORDATA_HEADER;
    };
};
```

and this:

```
struct SensorDataOverlay
{
    unsigned : 32;  // Skip uiTimestamp
    unsigned : 8;   // Skip ucDataType
    unsigned : 32;  // Skip uiDataSize

    struct T_SENSORDATA_HEADER;
};

union SensorDataMessage
{
    struct T_Message;
    struct SensorDataOverlay;
};
```

But none of that is working. In the end, I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
int Evaluate(SensorDataMessage msg)
{
    unsigned char tmp = msg.ucDataType;
    unsigned char tmp2 = msg.ucSensorType;
    [...]
}
```

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/a3bbz53t(v=vs.140)) I learned that what I want to do should be possible, but only in Visual C:

> A Microsoft C extension allows you to declare a structure variable
>   within another structure without giving it a name. These nested
>   structures are called anonymous structures. C++ does not allow
>   anonymous structures.
>
> You can access the members of an anonymous structure as if they were
>   members in the containing structure.

However, this seems not to be entirely true, since anonymous structs can be used in Visual C++ as well, like it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14248127).

I would highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found might help you out:

1. Have to change C/C++ compiler as **Compile as C code (/TC)** to gain anonymous structure support.

[image]

2. There's a missing keyword **union** on the declaration of **Evaluate()**
3. Anonymous native data type declaration in **SensorDataOverlay** seems would confuse the compiler, so I try to collect them into one single structure as **CommonHeader**, and put one pack in **SensorDataOverlay**.

I found **T_MESSAGE** and **SensorDataOverlay** shared the same scheme in the first three fields, I would say it would be better to be replaced as **CommonHeader**, would make more sense in perspective of data inheritance. Since at the beginning of question you pointed out that the **T_MESSAGE** is unchangeable, so I don't do any modification in the following code.

the complete code posted here, able to run, and I guess the memory offset scheme meets your needs.

---

```
*struct CommonHeader
{
    unsigned int  skipUiTimestamp;
    unsigned char skipUcDataType;
    unsigned int  skipUiDataSize;
};

struct SensorDataOverlay
{
    /* Use CommonHeader instead */
    //unsigned : 32;  // Skip uiTimestamp
    //unsigned : 8;   // Skip ucDataType
    //unsigned : 32;  // Skip uiDataSize

    struct CommonHeader;
    struct T_SENSORDATA_HEADER;
};

union SensorDataMessage
{   
    TT_MESSAGE;
    struct SensorDataOverlay;
};

int Evaluate(union SensorDataMessage msg)
{
    unsigned char tmp = msg.uiDataSize;
    unsigned char tmp2 = msg.ucSensorType;

    return 0;
}*
```