# Which C Features are influenced by/derived from C++ Features?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, standards, language-features

What are features from the actual C Standard, which originally weren´t part of C, but were invented in/for C++ and because of its benefits, were later adopted to C?

One prominent example is the single-line comment `//`, which originally came from C++ and later was adopted by C.

Do you know more features of the actual C Standard, which explicitly or implicitly came from the development of C++?

Info:
Of course, I know that C++ is derived from C but i was just thinking about which features was adopted from the development of its derivative, C++.

Comment: C's `_Bool` type was inspired by C++'s `bool` I believe.

Comment: Being able to declare variables in other locations than at the very top of a function was also a C++ first, later adopted by C I think.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Sure? This has been a feature of C much longer than most people think, and predates the first C++ standard.

Comment: I think function prototypes came from C++, IIRC.

Comment: Not allowing "implicit int" as a function return type (except for `main()`) is (I think) also something that C++ pioneered and C subsequently adopted.

Comment: @Konrad Am I sure? No. I explicitly said "I think". Which implies that I'm *not* certain. I'm going by my *memory* of reading the standards over the years, but I have not double checked my memory.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question with one clear answer, and there's no obvious problem here.

Comment: You can see the C99 directives

Comment: @JesperJuhl I think declaring variables inside an inner block of a function might predate C++, but mixing declarations and statements within a block probably came from C++ since it has only been a standard feature since C99.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: [Here](http://www.stroustrup.com/sibling_rivalry.pdf) B. Stroustrup relates the early history of C and C++.

Comment: Advancements to C were purposely put on hold during C++ nascent years.  Features that appeared first in C++ then C are then not necessarily due to "C++ has it so let's put it in C" as much as the C update was postponed and the feature came up in both.  I'm thinking of `//`, inline, and maybe others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot confirm that they were definitely influenced by C++ directly<sup>1</sup>, but here is a list of features in standard C++ that were added in C99:

- single line comments (as mentioned)
- inline functions
- variables allowed after beginning of block
- boolean datatype
- complex math library

C11:

- Anonymous unions (C11 allows anonymous structs too). Anonymous unions were already in standard C++. (Anonymous structs are still not allowed in standard C++).

<sup>1</sup> For example BCPL, predecessor of B which in turn is the predecessor of C already had same syntax for single line comments. Some of these may have been supported as language extensions in some C implementation prior to their incorporation to standard C++. In these cases both standard C and standard C++ may have been influenced by the same source, rather than influencing one another.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Anonymous: `union named { struct { int i;}; };` Unnamed: `union named { struct { int i;} unnamed; };`. The unnamed struct is has no name, but has a named variable. Anonymous struct is unnamed and has no named variable.

Comment: @Konrad https://stackoverflow.com/a/14248127/560648

Comment: Inline functions existed in GCC and other compilers before C++.

Answer (score 2):

[Attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Attributes) were added in C++11 and will be added in the next C standard revision [C2x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x). The [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2165.pdf) (and [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2175.pdf)) for this feature specifically references C++.

> Attributes can be useful for providing information that, for example, helps the compiler to issue better diagnostics or optimize the generated code. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Attributes)

Example:

```
int [[attr1]] i [[attr2, attr3]];

[[attr4(arg1, arg2)]] if (cond)

{
    [[vendor::attr5]] return i;
}
```

In this example, "*attribute attr1 applies to the type of variable i, attr2 and attr3 apply to the variable itself, attr4 applies to the if statement and vendor::attr5 applies to the return statement.*" [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Attributes)

Comment: Interesting, yet  "will be added" is not guaranteed.