# Union of unsigned short and anonymous bitfield

Tags: c++, unions, bit-fields

Minimal example:

```
union v1_t
{
    struct {
        unsigned int d1 : 4;
        unsigned int d2 : 4;
        unsigned int : 8;
    };
    unsigned short data;
};

union v2_t
{
    unsigned short data;
    struct {
        unsigned int d1 : 4;
        unsigned int d2 : 4;
        unsigned int : 8;
    };
};

int main()
{
    v1_t v1 {256}; // gets truncated to 0. This is the equivalent of v1_t {.d1=256}
    v2_t v2 {256};
}
```

The exact representation of my bitfields is different and is irrelevant here. The important part is that `v2_t` works as I expect and require (2 Bytes info with bitfields), but`v1_t` is truncating the data into 4 bits, exactly `d1`?

Comment: In case 1, the value 256 will be stored in `d1`. And it doesn't fit.

Comment: That makes sense in pragmatic terms. Do you have a link to a relevant documentation? Why isn't the first case considered as a group of many bitfields, for instance?

Comment: `256` binary representation is `100000000`

Comment: I don't have a formal description for all of Aggregate initialization. However, in this case [Brace elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Brace_elision) "allows" you to skip the inner braces for the struct (even if not intended).

Comment: That's really nice to know. Brace elision would not be applicable in `v2_t`. For now I will select `v2_t` because it is more intuitive (subjective). But if somebody has a formal description of the situation here, that would be really useful. "Why isn't the whole anonymous bitfield in `v1_t` considered a single entity?"

Comment: The issue is one of *initialization* and when initializing a bitfield with a value larger than the bitfielld can hold is *implementation defined*. See [Bit-field](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field). At most you can initialize `v1_t v1 {15, 15};` providing maximum values for `d1` and `d2`.

Comment: All makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: See [C++ Standard \[class.bit\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.bit#2) "*Unnamed bit-fields are not members and cannot be initialized.*"

Comment: Anonymous `struct` members are not valid in standard C++. They are supported by GCC and others as a non-standard extension.

Comment: @user17732522 thanks for the info. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248044/are-anonymous-structs-standard-and-really-what-are-they)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uniform initialization of the fields of each union will follow the order of the declared members.

For instance, `v1_t {256};` is the equivalent of `v1_t {.d1=256};` (C++20) which will obviously truncate the data (put down this way, the current behavior became obvious).

With `v2_t` on the other hand, the first data member is `data`, hence `v2_t {256};` is the equivalent of `v2_t {.data=256};` which is yielding the result and behavior I expected.

`v1_t` enables brace elision such as `{11, 2}` for `d1` and `d2` fields, respectively, but I have many different bit fields of different sizes and initialization must remain consistent from type to type.

The current standard in use in my project is C++17, hence the `{.data}` initialization possibility is not available and that is the reason why I consider `v2_t` the one providing the "expected" behavior.

Comment: "_which will obviously truncate the data (put down this way, the current behavior became obvious)._": It is not guaranteed that the value will be truncated. The behavior is implementation-defined per https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-16.9.sentence-4.