# How does C's grammar allow this unnamed nested struct?

Tags: c, parsing, struct, language-lawyer, grammar

The K&R and [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/summary-of-declarations) grammars for C indicate this simple struct:

```
struct { int a ; } ;
```

matches a `declaration` while parsing like this:

```
declaration
 declarationSpecifier ';'
  typeSpecifier ';'
   structOrUnionSpecifier ';'
    structOrUnion '{' structDeclarationList '};'
     'struct {' structDeclaration '};'
      'struct {' specifierQualifierList structDeclaratorList ';};'
       'struct {' typeSpecifier structDeclarator ';};'
        'struct { int' declarator ';};'
         'struct { int' directDeclarator ';};'
          'struct { int' identifier ';};'
           'struct { int a ;};'
```

and is therefore legal.  But if we nest it inside another struct like

```
struct { struct { int a ; } ; } ;
```

the parsing becomes:

```
declaration
 declarationSpecifier ';'
  typeSpecifier ';'
   structOrUnionSpecifier ';'
    structOrUnion '{' structDeclarationList '};'
     'struct {' structDeclaration '};'
      'struct {' specifierQualifierList structDeclaratorList ';};'
       'struct {' typeSpecifier structDeclarator ';};'
        'struct {' structOrUnionSpecifier declarator ';};'
         'struct {' structOrUnion '{' structDeclarationList '}' directDeclarator ';};'
          'struct { struct {' structDeclaration '}' identifier ';};'
```

which at this point is forcing an `identifier` where we don't want one as in `struct{struct{int a;}b;};` yet if we ignore that rule and leave out the `b` then `struct{struct{int a;};};` will still compile with no problem.

How and why is `struct{struct{int a;};};` compilable when the grammar indicates an additional `identifier` is required?  Have I misinterpreted the grammar or is the actual grammar not what I think it is?

**EDIT:**

"Unparsing" the desired `struct{struct{int a;};};` from the desired bottom up gives:

```
'struct { struct { int a ;};};'
'struct { struct { int' identifier ';};};'
'struct { struct { int' directDeclarator ';};};'
'struct { struct { int' declarator ';};};'
'struct { struct {' typeSpecifier structDeclarator ';};};'
'struct { struct {' specifierQualifierList structDeclaratorList ';};};'
'struct { struct {' structDeclaration  '};};'
'struct {' structOrUnion '{' structDeclarationList '};};'
'struct {' structOrUnionSpecifier ';};'
'struct {' typeSpecifier ';};'
'struct {' declarationSpecifier ';};'
'struct {' declaration '};'
```

but we're stuck again because a `struct{` must be followed by a `structDeclaration` not a `declaration`.

Comment: Where do you get the grammar from? Have you looked at the actual C specifications to see what the real grammar is?

Comment: And maybe it's just me, but I think that having two different structure rules, one for top-level structure and one for nested structures, would be a little too much. There's just one rule for structures, and it doesn't matter where or when the structure is defined. So the same rule that allows for top-level, non-nested unnamed structures without variable declarations, is the one that allows for unnamed structures without variable names nested inside other structures.

Comment: The grammar used is section A.13 page 193 of K&R and the learn.microsoft.com phrase structure grammar, which is the same for K&R as far as structs are concerned.

Comment: There are many levels here without any references.  `The K&R and Microsoft grammars for C` I have k&r here https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.txt but what is "microsoft grammars"? `will still compile` Why does "compile" indicate that something follows the grammar? What compiler, compiler options, compiler version you are using? `But if we nest it inside another struct like` Do the references claim that nested anonymous struct follows the grammar or you came up to the conclusion after testing yourself?

Comment: Finally, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/microsoft-extensions-to-c-and-cpp?view=msvc-170 unnamed anonymous structure is an _extension_ of MSVC (if you are using it) into C programming language. Bottom line, my point is "compilable" != "follows grammar". As I believe, unnamed structs are not available in K&R, but I am not sure if you are asking about K&R specifically? Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248044/are-anonymous-structs-standard-and-really-what-are-they answer your question?

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/summary-of-declarations) is Microsoft's claimed grammar for the C compiler declarations.  The whole point of the question is how unnamed nested structs are compiling when the grammar implies an identifier is necessary.  The compiler is Optimizing Compiler Version 19.37.32825 for x86 in Visual Studio 2022 with default options as installed.  Either the grammar or the parsing shown above are incorrect.  I don't understand which is the case.

Comment: As is now evident from the most recent postings, what Microsoft has documented in their grammar and what their compiler actually allows is two different things, and explains why I can't use the grammar to match the allowed nested structs.

Comment: K&R is a bad source since it is extremely outdated. Microsoft/MSVC is a bad source since it is explicitly not a conforming ISO C compiler -  they deliberately avoid following the C standard so using them as source is kind of like using a convicted criminal as source for how to interpret the law they were found guilty of breaking...

Comment: Instead see C17 6.7.2.1 (constraints): "A struct-declaration that does not declare an anonymous structure or anonymous union shall contain a struct-declarator-list". Meaning that a declaration containing an anonoymous structure need not. `struct { struct { int a ; } ; } x;` is perfectly fine and strictly conforming C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does C's grammar allow this unnamed nested struct?

The K&R C grammar does not allow this unnamed, anonymous nested structure.

This has changed in C11.

> How and why is struct{struct{int a;};}; compilable when the grammar indicates an additional identifier is required?

But, why not? Compilers have extensions. *Technically*, the C standard specifies what should happen with valid programs. The behavior of compilers is loose when compiling an invalid program (i.e. *undefined* behavior).

> Have I misinterpreted the grammar

No, it does't look like it.

> or is the actual grammar not what I think it is?

I compare with [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.txt](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c89/c89-draft.txt) "3.5 DECLARATIONS". It looks like your interpretation is fine.

> The whole point of the question is how unnamed nested structs are compiling

It's an extension in MSVC that allows for unnamed anonymous structures. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/microsoft-extensions-to-c-and-cpp?view=msvc-170 . It is quite confusing.

Comment: It's because I believed the declarations grammar documented at learn.microsoft.com that I couldn't figure out how nested structs were being parsed.

Comment: Hi. The "C grammar" refers to K&R grammar in OPs context.

Comment: There is no extension in use here. The Microsoft documentation that OP links to in a comment matches the current C standard; it has “opt” for the *struct-declarator-list*.

Answer (score 2):

Ref pg 193 of K&R (ANSI version)

```
declaration-specifiers:
    storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
    type-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
    type-qualifier declaration-specifiersopt

type specifier: one of
    void char short int long float double signed
    unsigned struct-or-union-specifier enum-specifier typedef-name
```

One of the elements of type specifier is struct-or-union.  The declaration-specifier is recursive and optional so you can have nested unnamed structs.

Comment: Yes, that's the grammar used for the parsing shown, and typeSpecifier is being parsed without including the declarationSpecifier.  It's the nested structDeclaration that's leading to the unwanted identifier.

Comment: That the *declaration-specifier* is recursive means you can have a list of declaration-specifiers, such as `long int`, `const int`, `const long int`, and so on, and that it is optional means the list can be finite in length. That is not the part of the rules that determines whether you need to have an identifier in the declaration. That rule is the production from *struct-declaration* to *specifier-qualifier list* *struct-declarator-list* `;`, and it changed in C 2011 to make the *struct-declarator-list* optional.

Answer (score 1):

This was not allowed in the K&R grammar. The C standard changed between the 2007 and 2011 versions to allow it. The production rule for *struct-declaration* changed from this in the 2007 version:

> *struct-declaration*:
>         *specifier-qualifier-list* *struct-declarator-list* `;`

to this in the 2011 version:

> *struct-declaration*:
>         *specifier-qualifier-list* *struct-declarator-list*<sub>opt</sub> `;`

Note [the Microsoft documentation you link to in a comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/summary-of-declarations?view=msvc-170) matches the C 2011 production; it has the subscript “opt” on the *struct-declarator-list* in the production from *struct-declaration*.